# How to update duplicated documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm having problems finding how to update a field when I find a duplicate.
What I need to do is:

Find documents that have same ipAddr, same bccId and have active True

If they have different sessionId field, I need to update the field active to false for the one with older lastUpdated.

At this point I'm trying to get all duplicates.
I found a couple links on how to do that, but none of them worked for me so far.

That's a scenario of one item that I would need to update:

```
db.mycollection.insert(
   [
        {
            "_id" : 12345,
            "bccId" : "1",
            "ipAddr" : "1",
            "sessionId" : "1",
            "updateTime" : ISODate("2010-02-11T01:05:35Z"),
            "active" : true,

        },

        {
            "_id" : 12346,
            "bccId" : "1",
            "ipAddr" : "1",
            "sessionId" : "2",
            "updateTime" : ISODate("2016-02-11T01:05:35Z"),
            "active" : true,

        },
   ]
)
```

They both have same bccId, ipAddr and active true, but have different sessionIds.

So after finding those two, I would need to compare their updateTime. The most recent should remain active. All the other should be updated so the active would be now false.

Hard coding the values, I could find the list of the duplicates like this:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([{ $match: { ipAddr: "1", bccId: "1", active: true } }])
```

But I couldn't figure out how to instead of using hard coded values, to make it compare between the other documents in the system.
And it didn't work when I tried to use groups, as there might be a good number of duplicates, I would need to get them by groups of same ipAddr and bccId I believe.
Also I'm not sure if that's the right approach to get the list and then compare the dates to update the fields.

After figuring it out I'll need to parse it to Java, so not sure if I should go straight to Java dev to create the query. If someone could help me out on the best approach to solve this problem it would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: why is your _id the same?

Comment: Sorry. Just a typo. Just changed the _id to be different

Comment: You can change your schema a bit to help you track *only* the active session by putting a unique index on `{ipAddr: 1, bccId: 1}`, such that only one entry is present always. To keep track of old sessions, you can keep them elsewhere in an auxiliary collection.

Comment: It wouldn't work... The client don't to apply any change to the structure so we can change anything there :P

Answer (score 0):

so here's what I did:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": 
        { 
            "active": true 
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort":
        {
            "updateTime": -1

        }
    },
    {
        "$group": 
        {
            "_id": 
            {
                "ipAddr": "$ipAddr", 
                "bccId": "$bccId"
            },
            "session": 
            {
                "$push": {
                    "sessionId": "$sessionId",
                    "updateTime": "$updateTime"
                }
            },
            "sessionCount":
            {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Using aggregation it will return me a Cursor. Then I just get the cursor iterate through it and perform the update I need on the active where the bccId and ipAddr are the same, and they are not equal to the session id on the top of the list (as I sorted the updateTime, the first one will be the most recent, which I want to keep active).

That's it :)